# PHP script to discover the form elements

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, curl

This is some weired query but I need an idea to start with ... So here it is ..

From my site when I click a button I want to go to other site like (facebook) and in there 2 form fields 1 will be username/email and other password auto fill with details from my first page ... :)

And one more thing there will be no defined sites like facebook , gmail etc users can give any site login page link and username and pass andd click submit and the login page will be auto filled  .... Not submitted :)

Is it ever Possible :)

Comment: browser extensions can do that, but website? javascript wont allow you to play with another site, but you can "proxy" the page using your php code and add javascript into it to autofill user/password

Comment: easy, google "php proxy script" :), there is a lot of open source applications that can do indirect browsing with cookies support plus more